# How to insert multiple rows using mybatis for each select statements in db2?

Tags: java, db2, mybatis, zos, db2-zos

in our project, we use Oracle and now we want our code to support Db2 v10 for Z/OS. There are a lot of situations where we insert multiple rows into a database dynamically and that is OK with Oracle but now for Db2 we are having a problem because mybatis and db2 are not really compatible(?).

Is there anyway or any mybatis config to fix this without using for loop in java code and insert individually(because of performance issue)?

Thanks for your help in advance

```
 INSERT INTO table
        (column 1, column 2,column 3,column 4 ,column 5 ,column 6 )
        <foreach item="element" collection="items" index="index" separator=" UNION ALL">
            SELECT
            value 1, value 2, value 3,value 4 ,
            value 5 ,value 6
            from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1

        </foreach>
```

I'm getting this error:

bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is

> com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error:
>   SQLCODE=-418, SQLSTATE=42610, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.16.53

Comment: The SQL looks syntactically invalid. Do you mean `union all select 1,2,3,4,5,6 from sysibm.sysdummy1`  ?

Comment: You may want to print the generated SQL statement before trying to execute it, it will let you see syntax errors more clearly. Since SQLCODE -418 indicates ["invalid use of parameter markers"](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/codes/src/tpc/db2z_n.html) I suspect what you posted is _not_ your actual statement.

Comment: this is the generated statement : INSERT INTO PF5RESERVERATE         (P5004COD, P5005COD,P5068SRL,P5068DT,P5068DURMNT,P5068RT)                        SELECT             8, ?, ?,current date ,             ? ,?             from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1            UNION ALL              SELECT             8, ?, ?,current date ,             ? ,?             from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1            UNION ALL              SELECT             8, ?, ?,current date ,             ? ,?             from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1

Comment: I guess maybe multiple select statements are the problem. because we tested and even two simple select queries threw exception and we found out that db2 does not execute two statements in a row so we separated them. but we don't know how to handle this. i appreciate your help

Comment: Try explicitly casting parameter markers to appropriate data types, e.g. `SELECT 8, CAST(? AS VARCHAR(10)), CAST(? AS INT),current date...` -- obviously use the actual data types of `P5005COD`, `P5068SRL` etc.

Comment: DB2 10 for z/OS is [out of service](https://www-01.ibm.com/software/support/lifecycleapp/PLCDetail.wss?q45=A375709J95876F78) as of 30-Sep-2017.  Its successor, DB2 11 for z/OS [will go out of service](https://www-01.ibm.com/software/support/lifecycleapp/PLCDetail.wss?q45=Y500397H59081K65) on 30-Sep-2020. The most current version of DB2 for z/OS is 12.